# If route parameter has a space at the end, my page returns 404?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a program that replaces a word within a text file, this word is replaced by the user through an input of type text. This changed word is passed through the URL under 'name' as an optional Url Parameter. However, if the user were to type in any word, for example 'orange' with a space at the end, for example 'orange ' , the page will result in a "Server Error in '/' Application" error, saying that the resource cannot be found (404), why does this happen, and is there anything I can do to prevent this error?

Below is my current route config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

The only alterations I have done thus far is by adding the additional 'UrlParamater.Optional' called name.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in the part of the URL that you enter.
I checked this myself and it worked without any problems. Be sure to check and see if the URL you entered is correct or not. You can create a new method and test yourself on it.